# How can I create and append to a Vec<Struct>?

Tags: vector, struct, rust

The following does not compile:

```
struct A {
    f: u16,
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<A> = Vec::new();
    let a = A { f: 42 };
    v.append(a);
}
```

But the compiler message seems to be leading me down the wrong path:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:14
  |
8 |     v.append(a);
  |              ^ expected mutable reference, found struct `A`
  |
  = note: expected type `&mut std::vec::Vec<A>`
             found type `A`
```

Editing the code to call `append` on a reference to `a`:

```
v.append(&mut a);
```

Also fails to compile, but with a surprising (to me) message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:18
  |
8 |         v.append(&mut a);
  |                  ^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found struct `A`
  |
  = note: expected type `&mut std::vec::Vec<A>`
             found type `&mut A`
```

Shouldn't `append` be looking for an element of the `Vec`?  It appears to be looking for a `Vec` itself.  Yet, I believe I'm following the proper creating for a `Vec` holding elements of type `A`.  From the Rust book:

> To create a new, empty vector, we can call the `Vec::new` function, as
>   shown in Listing 8-1.
>
> ```
> let v: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
> ```

(https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html)

I have successfully used `Vec<String>` using the same pattern I'm attempting here, but I'm clearly misunderstanding something quite fundamental.

Comment: This is append: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append -- The function you're looking for is push.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Since your comment answers the question, would you mind posting it as an s answer?

Comment: Thank you Benjamin Lindley, if you provide this information as an answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: Note that it's not a Python array. `append` has a different meaning for Rust `Vec`s.

Comment: Yes, Andrey Tyukin, I had managed to confuse myself because in another spot of my code I had intentionally chosen `append` (which is like Python's `extend`).  But since I'm new to Rust, I was lead down the wrong path by the compiler messages, and decided to post the question.  I'll happily accept the answer if Benjamin Lindley writes it up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think someone may have said this in the comments, but append appends all the elements of another vector into this one by moving them into Self, I think you're trying to `push(a)` onto your vec

Details: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/vec.html

```
let mut xs = vec![1i32, 2, 3];
println!("Initial vector: {:?}", xs);

// Insert new element at the end of the vector
println!("Push 4 into the vector");
xs.push(4);
println!("Vector: {:?}", xs);
```

Comment: Indeed, this is solved.  I was hoping to give @benjamin-lindley the credit for the accepted answer, since they were first.